# Unexpected exception raised by previous_page_number() method - Django Paginator

Tags: django, paginator

```
>>> objects = ['john', 'paul', 'george', 'ringo']
>>> p = Paginator(objects, 2)
>>> p.count
4
>>> p.num_pages
2
>>> page1 = p.page(1)
>>>
>>> page1.previous_page_number()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Rick\ws2\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py", line 136
, in previous_page_number
    return self.paginator.validate_number(self.number - 1)
  File "C:\Users\Rick\ws2\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py", line 38,
 in validate_number
    raise EmptyPage('That page number is less than 1')
django.core.paginator.EmptyPage: That page number is less than 1
>>>
```

According to the `previous_page_number()` documentation.

> `Page.previous_page_number()`
>
> Returns the previous page number. Raises `InvalidPage` if previous page doesn’t exist.

I was expecting `previous_page_number()` to raise `InvalidPage` exception as documentation says. Why it returning `EmptyPage` exception ?

Am I missing anything ?

Comment: Which django version you are using?

Comment: I am using django 1.10

Comment: But will invalid exception really matter? You can instead use has_previous to check for previous page instead of previous_page_number right?

Comment: Just curious I am nor looking for a workaround. So this is bug, right ?

Answer (score 0):

According paginator source(**django.core.paginator.py**) in 1.10:

```
def validate_number(self, number):
    """
    Validates the given 1-based page number.
    """
    try:
        number = int(number)
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        raise PageNotAnInteger('That page number is not an integer')
    if number < 1:
        raise EmptyPage('That page number is less than 1')
    if number > self.num_pages:
        if number == 1 and self.allow_empty_first_page:
            pass
        else:
            raise EmptyPage('That page contains no results')
    return number
```

As per your condition:  number will be less than 1 so it will raise

`EmptyPage('That page number is less than 1')`

But according Django docs it should have raised base exception 
**InvalidPage** !

This might be a typo mistake while writing the documentation for **[previous_page_number](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/pagination/#django.core.paginator.Page.previous_page_number)()**

But as per [InvalidPage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/pagination/#django.core.paginator.InvalidPage) explanation, **EmptyPage** exception comes under this only. So its nothing but a detailed/derived exception of InvalidPage.